# the text of datagridview disappears

Tags: c#, datagridview, telerik, telerik-grid, datagridviewcombobox

i am using telerik control(data grid view) in my project. but when i want to add new row in data grid, the text of previous rows (bindingSourceService.DataSource = dtservice ,  bindingSourceUnit.DataSource = dtunit) disappear. 
my datagridview has 3 combobox column.
what is wrong? please help me.

my codes:

```
public void FactorLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var cb = new CategoriBll();
               DataTable dtcategori = cb.GetAllDataCategori();
               bindingSourceCategouri.DataSource = dtcategori;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               ExceptionkeeperBll.LogFileWrite(ex);
            }
}
   private void DataGridViewFactorCellValueChanged(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var row = DataGridViewFactor.CurrentRow;
                if ((row != null) && (row.Cells[0].IsCurrent))
                {
                    var categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewFactor.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
                    var sb = new CategoriOptionBll();
                    DataTable dtservice = sb.ServiceGetById(categoryId);
                    bindingSourceService.DataSource = dtservice;
                }
                if ((row != null) && (row.Cells[1].IsCurrent))
                {
                    var serviceId = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewFactor.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
                    var cbi = new CostBll();
                    var dtunit = cbi.CostById(serviceId);
                    bindingSourceUnit.DataSource = dtunit;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionkeeperBll.LogFileWrite(ex);
            }
        }

        private void DataGridViewFactorCellEditorInitialized(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var row = DataGridViewFactor.CurrentRow;
                if ((row != null) && (row.Cells[0].IsCurrent))
                {
                    var categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewFactor.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
                    var sb = new CategoriOptionBll();
                    DataTable dtservice = sb.ServiceGetById(categoryId);
                    bindingSourceService.DataSource = dtservice;
                }
                if ((row != null) && (row.Cells[1].IsCurrent))
                {
                    var serviceId = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewFactor.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
                    var cbi = new CostBll();
                    var dtunit = cbi.CostById(serviceId);
                    bindingSourceUnit.DataSource = dtunit;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionkeeperBll.LogFileWrite(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Insert your data to database first , and reload this datasource to your Grid :)

Answer (score 0):

It will disappear because there will be only 1 value in the data source. Try adding value to the data source rather then assigning single value.

Comment: how can i do that? would you please explain?